# How do you use Ruby in Java?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

With JRuby, you can make use of Java libraries in Ruby. Is there the reverse for using Ruby libraries in Java?

Specifically I want to write an Eclipse plugin and I need to use a bunch of legacy functions in this library written in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for generating Java .class or .jar files from JRuby/Ruby

You can find the topic on the JRuby wiki: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/StandaloneJarsAndClasses

Doing that I believe you can do what you need.

Comment: The exact thing I needed was called jrubyc. Thanks